# jQuery .on('click') not working after reassignment in Edge/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

A client has reported this issue on IE 11.0.9600 (but works for me on 11.420.10586). I have been able to reproduce it on Edge 25.10586

This is with jQuery 1.9.1

What we have is a custom sharepoint page displaying items from a list. Part of the functionality is the ability to reorder and indent these items using arrow clicks. These clicks fire off some API calls to make the backend changes and the table is emptied. Then the items are re-read from the list and loaded into a table. At the end of this process click events are registered on the arrows + other functionality

On page refresh the first click works fine, and on occasion the following one or two with greatly reduced odds

```
var up = jQuery('#Table').on('click', '.Item div.arrow-up', moveItemUp)

var down = jQuery(".Item div.arrow-down");
down.on("click", moveItemDown);

jQuery(".Item div.arrow-left").on("click", moveItemLeft);
```

I have tried a few different ways of registering the click handlers but it hasn't changed anything. In the above code snippet "down" is being populated with references to however many items are in the list but clicks still do not work

```
jQuery('#Table').off();
```

Thinking it might have been getting confused with any previous handlers I put in this bit of code before the new ones are assigned, and after no affect, before the table is emptied before loading the new items. This made no change either

So I'm all out of ideas apart from updating jQuery but fknows what that might break

Cheers

Comment: Can you stand up a small demo, using as little code as possible?